# Show the new data inserted into MySQL table

Tags: php, session

I'm so glad to be here with you geniuses, and this is my first question here.

I create a web service for inserting data from android to a MySQL table on my PHP web server (a local server). I achieve this, but I can't figure out how to show the new data I just inserted (the new row in the MySQL table).

I need the new row of that table for transferring it by sessions to a another PHP page.
**I present for you my code and please forgive me for my English:**

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
<?php
    $b1= $_REQUEST['name_mobinaute'];
    $b2= $_REQUEST['cin_mobinaute'];
    $b3= $_REQUEST['email_mobinaute'];
    $b4= $_REQUEST['code_bancaire_mobinaute'];
    $b5= $_REQUEST['date_transaction_mobinaute'];

    $_SESSION['name_mobinaute'] = $b1; 
    $_SESSION['cin_mobinaute'] = $b2; 
    $_SESSION['email_mobinaute'] = $b3; 
    $_SESSION['code_bancaire_mobinaute'] = $b4; 
    $_SESSION['date_transaction_mobinaute'] = $b5;

    show  $_REQUEST['name_mobinaute'];
    show  $_REQUEST['cin_mobinaute'];
    show $_REQUEST['email_mobinaute'];
    show $_REQUEST['code_bancaire_mobinaute'];
    show $_REQUEST['date_transaction_mobinaute'];

    // Connexion au serveur de base de données
    $connect_result = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "azertga");

    if (!$connect_result) {
        echo("Impossible de se connecter au serveur de bases de données.<br>\n");
    } else {
        echo("Connecté au serveur de bases de données!<br>\n");
        // Selection de la base de données
        $select_result = mysql_select_db("mediashore");
    }

    if (!$select_result) {
        echo("Impossible de se connecter à la base de données.<br>\n");
    } else {
        echo("Connecté à la base de données!<br>\n");
    }

    $sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO clients_megamadou (C_nom, C_email, c_adresse, c_ncin) VALUES ('".$_REQUEST['name_mobinaute']."', '".$_REQUEST['email_mobinaute']."', '".$_REQUEST['adress_mobinaute']."', '".$_REQUEST['cin_mobinaute']."')");

    mysql_close();
?>
```

And this is the second page where I want to figure out the variables I just transferred:

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
<?php
    echo '<br />';
    echo 'Votre data1 est'.$_SESSION['name_mobinaute'];
    echo '<br />';

    echo '<br />';
    echo 'Votre data2 est'.$_SESSION['cin_mobinaute'];
    echo '<br />';

    echo '<br />';
    echo 'Votre data3 est'.$_SESSION['email_mobinaute'];
    echo '<br />';

    echo '<br />';
    echo 'Votre data4 est'.$_SESSION['code_bancaire_mobinaute'];
    echo '<br />';

    echo '<br />';
    echo 'Votre data5 est'.$_SESSION['date_transaction_mobinaute'];
    echo '<br />';
?>
```

I did all of this because I want to transfer my data received from my android application to another web server:

android(client) ===> web server **number 1** =====> web server **number 2**

Thanks and again; I'm so sorry for my English.

Comment: Forget using this code until you've read up about and understand how to avoid [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). As well, your PHP is completely broken. what's this "show" business?

Comment: Nothing to do with Android programming. You shouldn't label this question with Android tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, putting aside the fact that using PHP/MySQL this way is both frowned upon and terribly insecure, you can use:

```
$newRecordId = mysql_insert_id();
```

to get the ID of the last inserted record **IF** the table has an AUTO_INCREMENT primary key column.
Otherwise you're down to timestamping and retrieving the latest record **IF** no other inserts can happen via other requests, and that's very hacky and messy.

Also @thelawnmowerman is right, the android and web-services tags are wrong - just use php and mysql please.

*Edit*

It seems to me that the objective here is to collect some data sent via a POST/GET, insert it into a database table, and then display it. That can be achieved without the use of session variables or needing to get the latest record, all in a single page.

**Note** - I haven't completely cleaned up the way this is done - I have removed the invalid "show" statements and accounted for the fact that some of the request data does is not used in the insert, but is subsequently displayed.
If this is not how it needs to work, you will need to adjust this accordingly, and please bear in mind there is no sanitisation, cleaning, or validation of any of the data.

```
<?php
    // save request values to variables
    $name_mobinaute = $_REQUEST['name_mobinaute'];
    $email_mobinaute = $_REQUEST['email_mobinaute'];
    $adress_mobinaute = $_REQUEST['adress_mobinaute'];
    $cin_mobinaute = $_REQUEST['cin_mobinaute'];
    $code_bancaire_mobinaute = $_REQUEST['code_bancaire_mobinaute'];
    $date_transaction_mobinaute = $_REQUEST['date_transaction_mobinaute'];

    // Connexion au serveur de base de données
    $connect_result = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "azertga");

    if (!$connect_result) {
        echo("Impossible de se connecter au serveur de bases de données.<br>\n");
    } else {
        echo("Connecté au serveur de bases de données!<br>\n");
        // Selection de la base de données
        $select_result = mysql_select_db("mediashore");
    }

    if (!$select_result) {
        echo("Impossible de se connecter à la base de données.<br>\n");
    } else {
        echo("Connecté à la base de données!<br>\n");
    }

    // create sql statement for insert using variables set from request values
    $sql = "INSERT INTO clients_megamadou (C_nom, C_email, c_adresse, c_ncin) VALUES ('".$name_mobinaute."', '".$email_mobinaute."', '".$adress_mobinaute."', '".$cin_mobinaute."')";
    // execute insert and get result (will be true/false depending on success)
    $result=mysql_query($sql);

    if (!$result) {
        echo("Data failed to insert!<br>\n");
    } else {
        echo("Data inserted successfully:<br>\n");
        echo("- name_mobinaute: ".$name_mobinaute."<br/>\n");
        echo("- email_mobinaute: ".$email_mobinaute."<br/>\n");
        echo("- adress_mobinaute: ".$adress_mobinaute."<br/>\n");
        echo("- cin_mobinaute: ".$cin_mobinaute."<br/>\n");
        // these values were passed in via request, but were not inserted 
        echo("<br/>Other data:<br/>\n");
        echo("- code_bancaire_mobinaute: ".$code_bancaire_mobinaute."<br/>\n");
        echo("- date_transaction_mobinaute: ".$date_transaction_mobinaute."<br/>\n");
    }

    mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: ok sorry for that,I'm new here 
i remove now android ans web service tag
but what  i have to do please to make better my code

Comment: @menzous - No problem - if you have an auto-incrementing id column in your clients_megamadou table, the above should work. Use `DESC clients_megamadou` to see the table structure.

Comment: ok :)
this command show me the structure and C_ID have auto_increment in field EXTRA

Comment: $newRecordId = mysql_insert_id();
where i have to put this line please ??

Comment: this code
 `<?php
session_start();
$variablesSession = session_encode();
echo $variablesSession;
?>` 
give me :
**name_mobinaute|N;cin_mobinaute|N;email_mobinaute|N;code_bancaire_mobinaute|N;date_transactionmobinaute|N;**

how can i figure out to the value of this session vars???

Comment: **thx a lot :):):)
i try your code and this what i get:**

`Connecté au serveur de bases de données!
Connecté à  la base de données!
Data inserted successfully:
- name_mobinaute:
- email_mobinaute:
- adress_mobinaute:
- cin_mobinaute:

Other data:
- code_bancaire_mobinaute:
- date_transaction_mobinaute: `

**the data that i send it from android it's inserted into mysql table but it doesn't show in the browser !!!!!

what i have to do please!!**